# How to get keyframes of video ffmpeg for videos created by Red5?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, keyframe

I had a task of getting keyframes information of a video i.e. getting time duration of all keyframes(seeking video via rtmp url).
To get information of all the frames of video use following command:

```
ffprobe -show_frames testVideo.mp4 > data.txt
```

The information I get from data.txt file :

```
“keyframe=1” signifies that it tried to make keyframe
“pict_type=I” signifies a keyframe or I-frame
here I get exact time duration of keyframe.
```

actual fps of video

```
fps = coded_picture_number(last frame that contains coded_picture_number) / pkt_pts_time
```

Above information worked well for most of the videos.But for some videos that were created by Red5 were showing abnormal results.
List of urls I have searched
http://sinclairmediatech.com/using-ffprobe-to-evaluate-keyframes/
http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/How-can-I-find-the-keyframe-information-for-a-mp4-video-td4349687.html

please help if I am wrong or need any other command.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give the exact steps / software versions needed to generate the misbehaving video. More generic version: http://superuser.com/questions/885452/extracting-the-index-of-key-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Can you provide a short sample file?